# Docker container for OSGeo

Tags: osgeo, docker

Has anyone developed a docker container for OSGeo?  Currently, the bootable image can be downloaded from [here](https://live.osgeo.org/en/download.html).  It is set up to run in a virtual machine such as Virtual Box, but I am looking to run it through Docker.

Comment: Do any of the Docker containers on this list fit your needs? https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/DockerImages

Comment: That's it- thank you.  Somehow I missed that when I searched for it.

Answer (score 6):

There is a fairly large list of OSGeo Docker images [here](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/DockerImages) that are built on a variety of different base images. The page also contains information on the source, whether or not the image is on Docker Hub, and commentary on the project goals and status (e.g., under testing, works/doesn't work). One of these Docker images should fit your needs, or at least provide a starting point for a Docker container that you modify to suit your analysis.